# How to create a list field for uploading images through rest api in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-rest-api

I am at a loose of how to create a field for the user to upload images in the sharepoint list. The field has to be created through the rest api with the use of PowerAutomate

Tried looking for SP.Field equivalent and attributes like FieldTypeKind

Answer (score 0):

Try using SharePoint API call in Power automate using "Send HTTP Request to SharePoint" with this information:

[image]

**Method**: POST

**Uri**:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List Name')/fields/CreateFieldAsXml
```

**Headers**:

```
{
  "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
```

**Body**:

```
{
    "parameters": {"SchemaXml": "<Field DisplayName='My Image Column' Format='Thumbnail' IsModern='TRUE' Name='MyImageCol' Title='MyImageCol' Type='Thumbnail'></Field>"}
}
```